# IEEEtrans BiBTeX style: How to cite full author names (with unabbreviated given names)?

Tags: bibtex, ieeetran

I would like to cite author name as it is for examples

> Anne M.Jane

Please help

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
% all heading are same font size++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat*{\section}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries\sffamily}
%------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Georgia}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
%\usepackage{amssymb, amsfonts, amsthm, fouriernc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabto}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
%\usepackage{background}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage{datetime}
\newdate{date}{23}{09}{2016}
\date{\displaydate{date}}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{caption}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand\HRule{\rule{\textwidth}{1pt}}
\usepackage{tabularx} % extra features for tabular environment
\usepackage{amsmath}  % improve math presentation
\usepackage{graphicx} % takes care of graphic including machinery
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry} % decreases margins
\usepackage{cite} % takes care of citations
\usepackage[final]{hyperref} % adds hyper links inside the generated pdf file
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,       % false: boxed links; true: colored links
    linkcolor=blue,        % color of internal links
    citecolor=blue,        % color of links to bibliography
    filecolor=magenta,     % color of file links
    urlcolor=blue         
}

%\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{$\ast$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemii}{$\diamond$}
\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\bullet$}
%\renewcommand{\labelitemiii}{$\diamond$}
%++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
\begin{document}
identified : congruent, incongruent and semi-congruent melting\cite{Anne}.
\cleardoublepage

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{LiteratureReveiw}



\end{document}
```

/////////////////

```
@MastersThesis{Anne,
  author = {Mallow,Anne. M.},
  title  = {STABLE PARAFFIN COMPOSITES FOR LATENT HEAT THERMAL STORAGE SYSTEMS},
  school = {Georgia Institute of Technology},
  year   = {2015},
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really have anything to do with [tag:jabref]. Instead, you need to supply us with a minimal document that shows your setup, including the bibliography package that you might be using (like [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)), what bibliography style you're currently using, as well as a sample bibliography (in a `.bib` file, since you're using JabRef).

Comment: i am using IEEEtran  style

Comment: Nice, now just provide us with *more* detail...

Comment: Sorry more detail means? if we use IEEEtran, will it appear like A.M.Jane?

Comment: i am not using biblatex package

Comment: Please provide what we call a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile and see what you're currently seeing.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenient, i tried above name with word, it gives same answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45476/discussion-between-werner-and-arulraj-figurado).

Answer (score 1):

You have to do four things. In the preamble of your document (this means between `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}`), you have to insert the following lines:

```
\makeatletter
\def\bstctlcite{\@ifnextchar[{\@bstctlcite}{\@bstctlcite[@auxout]}}
\def\@bstctlcite[#1]#2{\@bsphack
  \@for\@citeb:=#2\do{%
    \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\csname #1\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi}%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother
```

These commands define a command `\bstctlcite`. You have to use this command immediately after `\begin{document}` as follows:

```
\bstctlcite{BSTcontrol}
```

Create the file `myIEEE.bib`; use an ordinary text editor (for plain text) and enter the strange looking BibTeX entry

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{BSTcontrol,
    CTLname_format_string = "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
}
```

as single entry (alternatively, you can put this entry into your regular `bib` file).
Finally, modify the `\bibliography` command in your document such that it reads

```
\bibliography{myIEEE, ... your bib files ...}
```

### Example

The pdf document

> [image]

is generated from the file `example.tex` containing

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\bstctlcite{\@ifnextchar[{\@bstctlcite}{\@bstctlcite[@auxout]}}
\def\@bstctlcite[#1]#2{\@bsphack
  \@for\@citeb:=#2\do{%
    \edef\@citeb{\expandafter\@firstofone\@citeb}%
    \if@filesw\immediate\write\csname #1\endcsname{\string\citation{\@citeb}}\fi}%
  \@esphack}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\bstctlcite{BSTcontrol}

identified : congruent, incongruent and semi-congruent melting\cite{Anne}.

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{myIEEE,LiteratureReview}
\end{document}
```

and from the bibliography files `myIEEE.bib` containing

```
@IEEEtranBSTCTL{BSTcontrol,
    CTLname_format_string = "{ff~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
}
```

and `LiteratureReview.bib` containing

```
@MastersThesis{Anne,
  author = {Mallow, Anne M.},
  title  = {STABLE PARAFFIN COMPOSITES FOR LATENT HEAT THERMAL STORAGE SYSTEMS},
  school = {Georgia Institute of Technology},
  year   = {2015},
}
```

by running the commands

```
pdflatex example.tex
bibtex example
pdflatex example.tex
pdflatex example.tex
```

(You can of course also use other TeX variants like `lualatex`, should work as well.)

### Links

[How to Use the IEEEtran BibTeX Style](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/bibtex/IEEEtran_bst_HOWTO.pdf), Section VII

[Oren Patashnik: Designing BibTeX styles](http://www.cse.cuhk.edu.hk/~tywong/latex_adv/bibtex.pdf), Section 5

Comment: When I give information. Jabref automatically make @Masterthesis{} , But when I copy @IEEEtranBSTCTL{} and past that above. It says problem of parsing entry. Then where can i put

Comment: `jabref` seems to be over-protective. Best paste the `@IEEEtranBSTCTL` into a separate `bib` file using a normal text editor and load it in addition to your regular `bib` file. See also my modified answer above. It is a good idea anyway to have the entry in a separate file.